# Can i create a clone of myself in 1.16?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been wondering if I can clone myself in minecraft, I have seen videos of people doing that. however,I am not sure if I can do that in the version I have.

Comment: Something like this? https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-pocket-edition/mcpe-mods-tools/1986592-npc-spawning-steve-code-needed

Answer (score 1):

You can't clone yourself in vanilla Minecraft. However, there are mods and server plugins that can do that.